# Points on the circle

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

We have $n$ points on the unit circle. What is the best configuration if we want to maximize the sum of the pairwise distances of the given points?

Comment: A regular *n*-sided polygon.

Comment: Could you send me a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can find the answer in

L. Fejes Tóth, "On the sum of distances determined by a pointset", Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar., 7:397–401, 1956.

Cheers, Z